# Android drawble-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi subfolders inside DRAWABLE-V21 also for DRAWABLE-V23?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I know it is not possible to add subfolders inside drawable-v21.
But how would I accomplish android to take different sizes of resources inside drawable-v21.
For example for:
drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi.

I need this behaviour -
(ic.png should be the same image with different pixel sizes)

- drawable-v21

  - drawable-xhdpi

    ic.png
  - drawable-xxhdpi

    ic.png
  - drawable-xxxhdpi

    ic.png
- drawable-v23

  - drawable-xhdpi

    ic.png
  - drawable-xxhdpi

    ic.png
  - drawable-xxxhdpi

    ic.png

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource qualifiers can be used in combination with each other (though there is a specific order that must be followed when combining them). All qualifiers and their precedence order are listed here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

You could, therefore, use a directory structure like this:

```
res/
    drawable-xhdpi-v21/
        ic.png
    drawable-xhdpi-v24/
        ic.png
    drawable-xxhdpi-v21/
        ic.png
    drawable-xxhdpi-v24/
        ic.png
```

Your own answer, however, implies that there is no difference between the `ic.png` file used for `v21` and `v24`. In this case, there's no need to specify the version at all:

```
res/
    drawable-xhdpi/
        ic.png
    drawable-xxhdpi/
        ic.png
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is exactly what I was looking for.
I will need to edit my answer because it is not complete. With my answer I think I could have less resources.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I realized I can solve my problem this way:

- drawable

  - ic_vector.xml
  - ic.png (1.0x)
- drawable-v21

  - outterDrawable.xml
- drawable-v23

  - outterDrawable.xml
- drawable-xhdpi

  - ic.png (1.0x)
- drawable-xxhdpi

  - ic.png (2.0x)
- drawable-xxxhdpi

  - ic.png (3.0x)

Where outterDrawable (drawable-v21) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Where outterDrawable (drawable-v23) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:src="@drawable/ic_vector" android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

Let me know is there is a different solution.